# Fetch as Google showing only "q"

Tags: magento, google-search-console, googlebot

I'm having an error with my website where it's not showing on Google any more. It had been well indexed last week, but now has no pages indexed. No major changes were made for this, but when I use the Googlebot Render in Fetch as Google, it shows just the letter "q". We have tried checking the source, but there is no "q" at line 13.

[image]

This is what shows in the "Fetching section":

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>
> Date: Thu, 05 Nov 2015 10:35:23 GMT
>
> Server: Apache/2.2.29 (Unix)
>
> X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.27
>
> Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
>
> Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
>
> Pragma: no-cache
>
> Set-Cookie: frontend=9b8ad36ddfa2cd7328e86c42920f7dca; expires=Thu, 05-Nov-2015 11:35:26 GMT; path=/; domain=www.example.com; HttpOnly
>
> Connection: close
>
> Transfer-Encoding: chunked
>
> Content-Type: text/html
>
> q

What can I do to make the page show correctly?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>COMPANY NAME</title>
<meta name="description" content="COMPANY NAME - Default Store View" />
<meta name="robots" content="INDEX,FOLLOW" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0;"> 
<link rel="icon" href="http://www.example.com/media/favicon/default/companyname_03.jpg" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.example.com/media/favicon/default/companyname_03.jpg" type="image/x-icon" />
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var BLANK_URL = 'http://www.example.com/js/blank.html';
    var BLANK_IMG = 'http://www.example.com/js/spacer.gif';
//]]>
</script>
<![endif]-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.example.com/skin/frontend/default/hellowired/css/widgets.css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.example.com/skin/frontend/default/hellowired/css/styles.css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.example.com/skin/frontend/default/hellowired/css/jquery.dialogbox.css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.example.com/skin/frontend/default/hellowired/css/custom.css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.example.com/skin/frontend/default/default/css/clnews/style.css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.example.com/skin/frontend/default/default/css/commercelab/treeview/jquery.treeview.css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.example.com/skin/frontend/default/hellowired/css/slider_product.css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.example.com/skin/frontend/default/default/css/print.css" media="print" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.example.com/js/lib/ccard.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.example.com/js/prototype/prototype.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.example.com/js/prototype/validation.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.example.com/js/scriptaculous/builder.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.example.com/js/scriptaculous/effects.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.example.com/js/scriptaculous/dragdrop.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.example.com/js/scriptaculous/controls.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.example.com/js/scriptaculous/slider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.example.com/js/varien/js.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.example.com/js/varien/form.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.example.com/js/varien/menu.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.example.com/js/mage/translate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.example.com/js/mage/cookies.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.example.com/js/jquery/jquery-1.7.1-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.example.com/js/commercelab/noconflict.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.example.com/js/commercelab/treeview/jquery.treeview.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.example.com/js/commercelab/category_tree.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.example.com/skin/frontend/default/hellowired/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.example.com/skin/frontend/base/default/js/imgpreview.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.example.com/skin/frontend/default/hellowired/js/hello.jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.example.com/skin/frontend/default/hellowired/js/less.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.example.com/skin/frontend/default/hellowired/js/cufon-yui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.example.com/skin/frontend/default/hellowired/js/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.example.com/skin/frontend/default/hellowired/js/custom.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.example.com/skin/frontend/default/hellowired/js/jquery.dialogBox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.example.com/skin/frontend/default/hellowired/js/random.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.example.com/skin/frontend/default/hellowired/js/jquery.scrollbox.js"></script>
<!--[if IE]>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.example.com/skin/frontend/default/hellowired/js/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.example.com/skin/frontend/default/hellowired/css/styles-ie.css" media="all" />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.example.com/js/lib/ds-sleight.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.example.com/skin/frontend/default/hellowired/js/pngfix.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.example.com/skin/frontend/base/default/js/ie6.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
optionalZipCountries = ["HK","IE","MO","PA"];
//]]>
</script>
<!-- BEGIN GOOGLE ANALYTICS CODEs -->
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-1111']);

_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
    
    (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();

//]]>
</script>
<!-- END GOOGLE ANALYTICS CODE -->
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
        var Translator = new Translate([]);
        //]]></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
     var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
//]]>
</script>
</head>

<body class=" cms-index-index cms-home" >

<script type="application/ld+json">
{
   "@context": "http://schema.org",
   "@type": "WebSite",
   "url": "http://www.example.com/index.php/",
   "potentialAction": {
     "@type": "SearchAction",
     "target": "http://www.example.com/index.php/catalogsearch/result/?q={search_term_string}",
     "query-input": "required name=search_term_string"
   }
}
</script><!--

-->

<div class="wrapper" style="z-index:1">

    <div class="inner-wrapper">

        <noscript>
        <div class="global-site-notice noscript">
            <div class="notice-inner">
                <p>
                    <strong>JavaScript seems to be disabled in your browser.</strong><br />
                    You must have JavaScript enabled in your browser to utilize the functionality of this website.                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </noscript>

    <div class="page">
    
            
<div class="header-container">
<div style="  background-color: #1b3f95;
    border: 2px solid #1b3f95;
    height: 13px;
    width: 99.70%;"></div>

    <div class="header" >

    
        <h1 class="logo"><strong>COMPANY NAME</strong><a href="http://www.example.com/index.php/" title="COMPANY NAME" class="logo"><img src="http://www.example.com/skin/frontend/default/default/images/logo_new.jpg" alt="COMPANY NAME" /></a></h1>

   
    <div class="cms-links">

     
    <ul>

    <li class="welcome"></li>





    


    </ul>

      
    </div>

   



       <div class="access">


          <div style="" class="store">

            <p><a href="http://www.example.com/index.php/store-locator"> Store locator </a> <a href="http://www.example.com/index.php/faq">FAQ</a></p> 
         </div>
          






          <div  class="shopping" style="font-weight:bold; position:relative;float:right;margin-right:64px; margin-top: -19px;">
        <a href="http://www.example.com/index.php/checkout/cart/" >
        <span style="font-weight:bold!important; color:#1B3F95">Shopping Basket:</span> <sapn class='counter' style="font-weight:bold; color:#1A4095;">0 &nbsp;items </sapn>
        </a>
    </div>





            

       </div>

       <!--

    this url for cart moves   -->


<div style=" float: right;height: 42px;margin-right: 126px;margin-top: 46px; width: 399px;">

      
<form id="search_mini_form" action="http://www.example.com/index.php/catalogsearch/result/" method="get">

    <div class="form-search"  style=" margin-right: 100px;width: 207px; height:25px">

        <label for="search">Search</label>

        <input id="search" type="text" name="q" value="" class="input-text"  style="width:167px; margin-left: 28px;"/><img style="margin-top: -20px;padding-left: 4px;" src="http://www.example.com/skin/frontend/default/hellowired/images/search1.jpg"/>
       <div id="search_autocomplete" class="search-autocomplete"></div>

        <script type="text/javascript">

        <![CDATA[

            var searchForm = new Varien.searchForm('search_mini_form', 'search', 'Search entire store here...');

            searchForm.initAutocomplete('http://www.example.com/index.php/catalogsearch/ajax/suggest/', 'search_autocomplete');

        //]]>

        </script>

    </div>

   <input type="image" class="search_btn" src="http://www.example.com/skin/frontend/default/hellowired/images/companyname-search.jpg" value="Go" style="  float: right;height: 33px;margin-right: -285px;margin-top: 6px;"/> 

</form>

      
  </div>


    <div style="float: right;margin-right: -485px;margin-top: 52px;width: 85px;">


     <a href="https://twitter.com/companyname" > <img style="width:40px;float:left" src="http://www.example.com/skin/frontend/default/default/images/twitter-2.jpg" class=""></a>

     <a href="https://www.facebook.com/companyname" ><img style="width:40px;float:left;margin-left:-5px" src="http://www.example.com/skin/frontend/default/default/images/fb-2.jpg " class=""></a>




  </div>



        


    <div id="navigation" >

        <div class="nav-container">
            <ul id="nav">
                <li class="level0"><a href="/index.php/" style="text-decoration:none; border:none; color:rgb(25, 65, 139)" class=""><span> Home</span></a></li>
                <li class="level0 nav-1"><a href="/index.php/about-us"><span>ABOUT US</span></a></li>               
                <li class="level0 nav-1"><a href="/index.php/shop.html"><span>SHOP</span></a></li>
                <li class="level0 nav-2"><a href="/index.php/recipes.html"><span>Recipes</span></a></li>
                <li class="level0 nav-3"><a href="/index.php/cocktails.html"><span>Cocktails</span></a></li>
                <li class="level0"><a href="/index.php/awards"><span> AWARDS </span> </a></li>
                <li class="level0"><a href="/index.php/our-news"><span> BLOG </span> </a></li>              
                <li class="level0"><a href="/index.php/contact-us"><span> CONTACT US</span> </a></li>        
            </ul>
<div style="clear: both; overflow: hidden; height: 30px; border-top: 2px solid #000; border-bottom: 2px solid #000; margin-top: 55px; width:888px">  
  <div style="float: left; width: 49.7%; text-align: center; border-right: 2px solid #000; margin-top: 6px;"><a href="/index.php/delivery-information" style="color: #1B3F95; text-decoration: none;">DELIVERY INFORMATION</a></div>
  <div style="float: left; width: 50%; text-align: center; margin-top: 6px;"><a href="/index.php/price-changes" style="color: #1B3F95; text-decoration:none">RECENT PRICE CHANGES</a></div>
</div>

</div>  


    



    


    <div class="clearfix" ></div>



    </div>

    
<script type="text/javascript">


jQuery(document).ready(function() {
          jQuery('.toggle').click(function() {
               if (jQuery('.submenu').is(":hidden"))
               {
                    jQuery('.submenu').slideDown("fast");
               } else {
                    jQuery('.submenu').slideUp("fast");
               }
               return false;
          });
          
});


</script>
<div id="menu" class="hidden-desktop">

      <!--div class="menutop clearfix">
        <a class="toggle">Categories <span></span></a> 
      </div-->
        <ul id="left-nav" class="submenu" style="display:none;">
                                                
                                        <li class="category "> 
                        <a href="http://www.example.com/index.php/shop.html" >
                            SHOP                        </a>
                        <span class="arrow" lang="6"><i></i></span>                 </li>
                                        <li>
                        <ul class="subcategory_6 subcategory" style="display:none;">
                                                                                                                            <li class="category cate " lang="13">
                                    <a href="http://www.example.com/index.php/shop/bottle.html" >
                                        Bottle                                  </a>
                                                                    </li>
                                                                                                                                                            <li class="category cate " lang="14">
                                    <a href="http://www.example.com/index.php/shop/signature-boxes.html" >
                                        Signature Boxes                                 </a>
                                                                    </li>
                                                                                                                                                            <li class="category cate " lang="15">
                                    <a href="http://www.example.com/index.php/shop/gift-range.html" >
                                        Gift Range                                  </a>
                                                                    </li>
                                                                                                                                                            <li class="category cate " lang="16">
                                    <a href="http://www.example.com/index.php/shop/signature-range.html" >
                                        Signature Range                                 </a>
                                                                    </li>
                                                                                                                                                            <li class="category cate " lang="20">
                                    <a href="http://www.example.com/index.php/shop/hampers.html" >
                                        Hampers                                 </a>
                                                                    </li>
                                                                                    </ul>
                    </li>
                                                                                    
                                        <li class="category "> 
                        <a href="http://www.example.com/index.php/recipes.html" >
                            Recipes                     </a>
                                            </li>
                                                                                    
                                        <li class="category "> 
                        <a href="http://www.example.com/index.php/cocktails.html" >
                            Cocktails                       </a>
                                            </li>
                                                        </ul>
</div>




    


    


</div>

<style>





#nav_menu{width:100px; padding-bottom:10px;height:auto; background-color:#19479C;display:none;float:left;border:2px solid #1B3F95;position: absolute;z-index: 100;n opacity: 1; margin-top: 5px; padding-top:10px;padding-left:20px;padding-right:20px;}

#nav_menu ul{ padding-left: 33px;float: left;color:white!important;}

#nav_menu ul li a:hover{color:white!important; font-weight: bold;float: left; text-decoration:underline;}
.shopping a:hover{text-decoration: none}

</style>



        <div class="main-container col1-layout">

            <div class="main row">

                
                <div class="col-main span12">

                    
                    <div class="std"><p style="margin-left: 56px; margin-top: 10px;"><img src="http://www.example.com/media/wysiwyg/irish_cream_heart_home_1024x335.jpg" alt="" width="888" /></p>

<div style="width: 888px; margin-left: 56px; color: #8c9091; font-family: Georgia; font-size: 17px; height: 167px; overflow: hidden; padding: 7px;">

<p style="text-align: center;">PARAGRAPH TEXT</p>

<p style="text-align: center;">PARAGRAPH TEXT<a style="text-decoration: none; color: #8c9091;" href="about-us">READ MORE...</a></p>

</div>

<p><br /> &nbsp; <br /> &nbsp; <br />&nbsp;</p>

<div class="top-product"><div class="top-products"><div class="spot-image"><a href="http://www.example.com/index.php/pourer.html"><img src="http://www.example.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/265x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/p/o/pourer.jpg"></a></div>
        
        <div class="spot-link"><a href="http://www.example.com/index.php/pourer.html">Pourer</a></div></div><div class="top-products"><div class="spot-image"><a href="http://www.example.com/index.php/50-mini-with-hot-chocolate.html"><img src="http://www.example.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/265x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/m/i/minichoc-300.jpg"></a></div>
        
        <div class="spot-link"><a href="http://www.example.com/index.php/50-mini-with-hot-chocolate.html">50 Mini with hot chocolate</a></div></div><div class="top-products"><div class="spot-image"><a href="http://www.example.com/index.php/mini-with-truffle.html"><img src="http://www.example.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/265x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/m/i/minitruffle-300.jpg"></a></div>
        
        <div class="spot-link"><a href="http://www.example.com/index.php/mini-with-truffle.html">50 Mini with truffle</a></div></div></div>

<div style="clear: both;">&nbsp;</div>

<div style="overflow: hidden; margin-bottom: 20px;">

<div style="float: left; margin-left: 56px;">

<h2 class="store-data" style="width: 100%;"><a style="color: #8c9091; font-family: Georgia; font-size: 19px; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none;" title="Shop" href="/index.php/shop.html">Online Shop</a></h2>

<a style="color: #8c9091; font-family: Georgia; font-size: 19px; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none;" title="Shop" href="/index.php/shop.html"><img style="color: #8c9091; font-family: Georgia; font-size: 19px; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none;" src="http://www.example.com/media/wysiwyg/shop-home-page_402_x_400.jpg" alt="" width="402" height="400" /> </a></div>

<div style="float: right; padding-right: 15px;">

<h2 class="store-data" style="width: 100%; color: #8c9091; font-family: Georgia; font-size: 19px; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none;"><a style="color: #8c9091; font-family: Georgia; font-size: 19px; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none;" title="Recipes" href="/recipes.html/">Recipes</a></h2>

<a style="color: #8c9091; font-family: Georgia; font-size: 19px; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none;" title="Recipes" href="/recipes.html"><img src="http://www.example.com/media/wysiwyg/CS_RECIPE-IMAGE-FOR-HOME-PAGE-402-X-400.jpg" alt="" /></a></div>

</div></div>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

        

 <div style="background-color;#ffffff;" class="copyright" >

<div style=" background-color: #1f3c98;height: 6px; margin-left: 38px;width: 888px"></div>
        <div class="f-left">

           <div style="float: left; margin-top: 20px; width: 888px; margin-left: 37px;">

<div class="footer-links">

<h3 style="color: #676b6a; font-weight: bold; font-size: 17px; font-style: italic;">Here to help</h3>

<ul style="list-style-type: none; line-height: 7px;">

<li style="color: #cdcdcd;"><a style="font-size: 15px; font-weight: normal;" href="http://www.example.com/index.php/delivery-information">Delivery Information</a></li>

<li style="padding-top: 10px; color: #cdcdcd;"><a style="font-size: 16px; font-weight: normal;" href="http://www.example.com/index.php/faq">FAQ</a></li>

<li style="padding-top: 10px; color: #cdcdcd;"><a style="font-size: 16px; font-weight: normal;" href="http://www.example.com/index.php/price-changes">Price Changes</a></li>

</ul>

</div>

<div class="footer-links">

<h3 style="color: #676b6a; font-weight: bold; font-size: 17px; font-style: italic;">Legal</h3>

<ul style="list-style-type: none; line-height: 7px;">

<li class="last privacy" style="color: #cdcdcd;"><a style="font-size: 15px; font-weight: normal;" href="http://www.example.com/index.php/privacy-policy-cookie-restriction-mode">Terms and Conditions</a></li>

<li style="padding-top: 10px; color: #cdcdcd;"><a style="font-size: 15px; font-weight: normal;" href="http://www.example.com/index.php/privacy-policy-cookie-restriction-mode">Privacy &amp; Cookies</a></li>

</ul>

</div>

<div class="footer-links">

<h3 style="color: #676b6a; font-weight: bold; font-size: 17px; font-style: italic;">About us</h3>

<ul style="list-style-type: none; line-height: 7px;">

<li style="color: #cdcdcd;"><a style="font-size: 15px; font-weight: normal;" href="http://www.example.com/index.php/contact-us">Contact us</a></li>

<li style="color: #cdcdcd; padding-top: 10px;"><a style="font-size: 15px; font-weight: normal;" href="http://www.example.com/index.php/news.html">News</a></li>

<li style="color: #cdcdcd; padding-top: 10px;"><a style="font-size: 15px; font-weight: normal;" href="http://www.example.com/index.php/customer-login">Login</a></li>

</ul>

</div>

<div class="footer-links">

<h3 style="color: #676b6a; font-weight: bold; font-size: 17px; font-style: italic;"><a href="/index.php/awards">Awards Page</a></h3>

<ul>

<li>List Ite,</li>

</ul>

</div>

<div style="margin-top: 44px; text-align: center; clear: both; color: #808080;">Copyright &copy; 2015 COMPANY NAME.</div>

</div>
            <address></address></div>

            <div class="f-right">

            

            </div>

            

            <div style="clear:both;"></div>

            </div>

  


        
    </div>

    </div> <!-- end .inner-wrapper-->

</div>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: We can't possible tell why the code you haven't shared with us is sending Google nothing by the letter q.

Comment: Have added full page code.

Comment: https://validator.w3.org/nu/ would probably be a good start.

Comment: That points out some minor errors, but nothing that looks like it should cause nothing to show in the Fetch.

Comment: @Ronan Check your `/robots.txt`.
It might also be possible that your webserver is configured to block googlebot for some reason

Comment: @TRGWII Yes, I have done this, and updated the robots.txt just in case this was the issue. Unfortunately, it is not.

Comment: It looks like your application treats requests with Googlebot useragent in a different way than browser requests. May be this is some mistake in your application. Or may be your site is hacked. Try to setup development environment on your site and test requests with googlebot useragent. May be you can find some code in your routing or middleware.

Comment: My first hunch was robot.txt.  I agree on @Alex's comment on hack, since it happened to me too.  htaccess file on perhaps a double entry.  Another thought makes me think that a script could be interfering/overlap that spits out a p.. or even some typo within a calculation of some sorts.. sorry, wish to be more specific but there are not enough documents to look into.

Comment: This is because some of your extension or or code checking the user agent and returning just "q",  You can find who is doing this by searching in to your code pool for the event "controller_action_predispatch" and check the login what they doing, if it's unwanted for your site just delete or remove the event observer.

Comment: There is a missing /> in line <meta name="viewport" ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something similar happened to one site I was working on a year ago and it ended up being a problem with an extension I was using.

- Go to System -> Cache Management and disable the cache
- Then go to System -> Configuration
- Find any extension installed and disable them all (if possible)
- With the extensions disabled (or uninstalled via the Connect Manager) check with Google and see if it renders the page correctly.
- If it renders correctly then enable/reinstall the extensions one by one until it stops rendering correctly and you will have your culprit.

Answer (score 0):

"q" is a common name for custom search forms in Magento. If your site has a custom template, make sure that there is no problem with the functions that use them.